# Android Studio 3.2.1 não localiza "Default Activity"

Tags: android, android-activity, kotlin, build, default

Pessoal estou com esse problema desde o Android 3.2. Já fiz os seguintes procedimentos para tentar fixar o problema:
- Já fiz clean e rebuild do projeto
- Já limpei o cache e reiniciei o Android Studio
- Já fiz sync com o Gradle (esse funciona, mas só deixa instalar o app uma única vez, depois dá erro de novo)
- Já apaguei e recriei o projeto várias vezes (nunca adianta)

Podem me dar uma ajuda? Já nem sei mais o que fazer. Seguem os prints abaixo.

[image: AndroidManifest]
[image: Run Configurations]
[image: App build.gradle]
[image: BaseActivity.kt]

Comment: Dê preferencia a postar o código, não imagens... aqui no Sopt utilizamos seu proprio codigo para lhe ajudar

Answer (score 1):

Você poderia fazer alguns testes?

1. No OnCreate() da sua BaseActivity setar o contentView.

   setContentView(R.layout."SeuLayout")
2. Tentar setar na mão qual activity é seu launcher, seguindo o seu segundo screenshot, onde está "Default Activity" muda para "Specified Activity" e no campo abaixo seleciona sua base activity.

Answer (score 1):

Tente zerar o Cache do Android Studio em:

**File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart...**

Caso não funcione, certifique-se que todos os caminhos de SDK, JRE e NDK, estão atualizados e apontando para os caminhos corretos de instalação. Em:

**File > Project Structure > SDK Location**

E os pacotes de versão do SDK em:

**File > Settings > Apperance & Behavior > System Settings > Android SDK**