# Android Studio - Layout XML não mostra opções e sempre dá erro

Tags: android, xml, layout, kotlin

Todo e qualquer layout que eu crie não mostra elementos como LinearLayout, RecyclerView e outros. Somente as opções abaixo (e os erros também)
[image: Erro]

Além disso, o XML sempre está com erro falando que está faltando width ou height, mas está tudo certo (como na imagem acima). Já importei tudo o que tinha que importar mas infelizmente o erro continua.
[image: Erro de Layout 2]

**Clean, rebuild, sync e invalidate cache não funcionam.** Além sabe o que pode ser?

**Informações adicionais:**
- Tudo começou no Android 3.2.1
- Também estou com outro problema que pode estar interligado: [Android Studio 3.2.1 não localiza "Default Activity"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/337759/android-studio-3-2-1-n%C3%A3o-localiza-default-activity)

Answer (score 0):

Aconteceu comigo também. pra resolver foi só fazer um downgrade de versão do android studio

1- Desinstale a versão atual do seu sistema.
2-baixe a versão mais antiga do FileHippo.com - Faça o download do software livre, pois eles mantêm um arquivo de todas as versões mais antigas do software.
instale-o.
3-Quando o Android Studio pede uma nova atualização, apenas negue.